# How do I update a sub-document in MongoDB without querying the parent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following MongoDB Schema:

```
let ChannelSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
}, { timestamps: true })

let UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: [true, "username_required"], unique: true},
  channel: [ ChannelSchema ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

I am trying to create an endpoint that toggles the active status of my Channel schema. However, when I created the following test code the response is `undefined`

```
router.post('/deactivate', async (req, res, next) => {
  let channelId = req.body.channelId;
  let channel = await Channel.findOneById(channelId});
  res.json(channel);
});
```

How do I select a channel by its id, in this instance, and change the active status to false? I would prefer not to have to select the User document first. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use $set for hash fields and positional update operator for array fields.

Comment: I'll have to look into those, ty

Answer (score 0):

If you using mongoose as ORM you should use findById instead of findOneById

```
let channel = await Channel.findById(channelId});
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually threw this sample together quick and actually have been using findById

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
router.post('/deactivate', async (req, res, next) => {
  let channelId = req.body.channelId;
  let channel = await User.findOneAndUpdate({'channel._id': channelId}, { 'channel.$': 1 });
  res.json(channel);
});
```

I would explain it but I don't understand completely why it works just yet.